# Is this a pleonasm?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, word-choice

I quote Booker T. Washington:

> I pity from the bottom of my heart any nation or body of people that is so unfortunate as to get entangled in the net of slavery.

I wonder whether “to get entangled in the net” is a pleonasm or not.

Comment: Closer to pleonasm is the pairing of “nation” and “body of people”, but I don't think that qualifies either.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung, the terms “nation” and “body of people” represent two different aspects:  on the one hand, nations that allow slavery; on the other, races whose people were  enslaved

Comment: @jwpat7 I wasn't suggesting that those two terms _are_ a pleonasm, just pointing out that they at least _could be._ I don't see how “entangled in the net” could possibly represent a pleonasm, so I thought I'd point out that there are terms in this quotation with more potential for overlap.

Comment: I agree that Mr. Washington could have said, "... as to get entrangled in slavery" without much loss of meaning. _Entangled_ is a vivid enough word that it conveys the sense of a "net" or a "trap." That said, I don't think I'd go so far as to say that the words "in the net" qualify for a pleonasm. I wouldn't call them "superfluous" as they do eliminate a measure of speculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pleonasm is the use of redundant or meaningless words.

In this case, Washington is using a metaphor, implying that slavery is a net; it is something which effectively traps one.

If it were a pleonasm, he would have needed to include additional words that added no meaning, except perhaps to lend a poetic or creative touch.

For example: "...as to get caught, entangled in the net of slavery."

Although "caught" and "entangled" are not precisely synonyms, they both suggest the same predicament with respect to a net. Such an example could be considered a pleonasm.

Comment: “...entangled in the tangle...” might be another hypothetical pleonasm.